# Loaded relationship changes inside Job class because of Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a job class that accepts a `User`. I load a `hasMany` relationship in that model inside the constructor, using a closure. Somehow, the result gets changed as if the closure was thrown away when it reaches the `handle` method.

Something like this:

```php
class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected User $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        // load children relationship where field = 3
        $this->user = tap($user)->load([
            'children' => function ($children) {
                $children->where('field', 3);
            }
        ]);

        dump($this->user->children->toArray());
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        dump($this->user->children->toArray());
    }
}
```

Using the sync Queue driver, I made a route to dispatch this job and check the results in the browser. The dumped results are different.

According to laravel debugbar, the relationship query is repeated inside `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php:102` but without the Closure.

| query | location |
| --- | --- |
| select * from "users" where "users"."id" = 6 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1 | \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:23 |
| select * from "children" where "children"."usuario_id" in (6) and "field" = 3 and "children"."deleted_at" is null | \app\Jobs\SomeJob.php:30 |
| select * from "users" where "users"."id" = 6 limit 1 | \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php:102 |
| select * from "children" where "children"."usuario_id" in (6) and "children"."deleted_at" is null | \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php:102 |

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Which is the reason about use tap() helper in tap($user).  Wjy not, directly $user->load(... )

Comment: Could you paste children relation definition in user model?

Comment: why don't you just do it in the handle method?

Comment: The reason for tap() was basically to be fancy and do it in a one liner. It's equivalent of doing `$this->user = $user; $this->user->load('children');`

Comment: @lagbox no real reason. I was just very surprised to find this odd behavior

Comment: I think Manuel was asking why you are using `tap` because `load` returns the model it is called on already, so `tap` isn't needed here .... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L498

Comment: @lagbox. Oh, it does! I got confused with something else. Then tap has no reason to be there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the model is serialized in this way there is only an 'identifier' used. It isn't actually serializing the model how `serialize` would. This is why it has to query for the model when unserialized, as there is only an identifier to find the model again.

It knows to load the relationships after unserializing because that information is saved with the identifier for the model, but it is only what relationship has been loaded, not how it was loaded or what is currently in it. So it then will load the relationships that were previously loaded via a simple call to `load` with the name of the relationship when unserialized.

Open up that trait `SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers` and you will see how it does this.

Comment: [SerializesModels](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesModels.php) and [SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Queue/SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers.php)

Answer (score 0):

Construct in jobs works not as usual class constructor. It's used by SerializesModels to serialize and deserialize the model passed, but I don't think that your tap really executed (except the sync driver when data not serialized)

that's why your handle method loads users and all related children instead of filtered.

You need to move children loading to handle method

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->user->load([
        'children' => function ($children) {
            $children->where('field', 3);
        }
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The tap executes correctly in the constructor. The dumped data in the constructor is what I expect and the query shows up in the query log. I know I can load the relationship in the handle method but what I really don't understand is why the load Closure doesn't get taken into account by the model serialization. That's the thing I really want to know.